# Where do I change the ACTUAL title tag that is set in the header.php

Tags: title

I am new to WordPress, and have been asked to change a value in the title tag.
The title tag is of the format: "site name | slogan" which is set dynamically in the header.php (seems standard code for WordPress from what I can see from other posts).

It is the slogan on the home page only that I need to change.
All other pages within the site are ok, I just need to change the home page, and I have no idea if this "slogan" portion of the title is coded somewhere, or set as an attribute etc.
Where and how do I change it?? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things.  The first, recommended way would be to use a plugin like [WordPress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/).  Install it, and replace the `<title>` tag in your `header.php` file with:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Or you can change the title only for the home page by using the `is_front_page` or `is_home` conditionals.

```
<title>
<?php
bloginfo('name'); // this is the blog name
echo ' | '; // seperator
if(is_front_page())
{
    // what you want for the home page here
}
else
{
    bloginfo('description'); // this is the slogan
}
</title>
```

That's a bit sloppy though, and I'd recommend looking into using [`wp_title`](http://%3Ctitle%3E%20%3C?php%20bloginfo%28%27name%27%29;%20//%20this%20is%20the%20blog%20name%20echo%20%27%20%7C%20%27;%20//%20seperator%20if%28is_front_page%28%29%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20//%20what%20you%20want%20for%20the%20home%20page%20here%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20bloginfo%28%27description%27%29;%20//%20this%20is%20the%20slogan%20%7D%20%3C/title%3E) instead.

Twenty Eleven's `header.php` has a good example of [this](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php):

```
<title><?php
/*
 * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
 */
global $page, $paged;

wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

// Add a page number if necessary:
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code from Twenty Eleven you provided above is exactly the code I have in the header.php file.  So I think it is the actual header name that I need to change. Do you how I do that?

Comment: So I think it is the actual blog description that I need to change.  Not just dynamically, but permanently for the site.

Comment: Found it!! Thanks for your help. It was under the General Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin dashboard > Settings > General

You are getting General Settings...

All Settings is be their....